# Leads limit for importing leads using bulk api call in marketo

Tags: marketo

Anyone know the max leads limit for importing leads in bulk using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined limit for the number of leads that can be imported through the Import Lead REST API endpoint. But there is a file size limit of 10MB in place that does act as the relevant limit in this case. So the number of leads that can be imported goes down, as you increase the number of fields/attributes per lead.

I updated the [Marketo API documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/import-lead/) to clarify this.